# Calculate the discrete set of points B which are in the convex hull of the set of points A

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, linear-programming

This problem is likely best described with the following picture:

[image: Set $A$ shown in blue, set $B$ shown in red, bounding box shown with black lines]

Given the discrete set of points $A$ (shown in blue), I wish to calculate the discrete set of points that are contained within the convex hull of set $A$, producing set $B$ (shown in red). Note that it is not necessarily required to calculate the convex hull itself, although it may be advantageous to do so.

I have been able to achieve this by testing whether each point within the bounding box (shown in black) is linearly separable from the entire set $A$ (using linear programming). However this is very slow when set A is large and in higher dimensions and I feel like testing each point is not necessary.

Preferably I'd like some advice on where to look for optimizing my search for points. Maybe fit a rectangle inside to avoid testing all points? I'm just looking for ideas or other solved methods.

For my application I need to extend this to 3D but I find solving these problems in 2D and generalizing much easier.

Comment: although this question is upvoted and mathoverflow has smart people, you might get more informed answers at the scicomp stackexchange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of blue points $A$. You can compute the convex hull of $A$
in $O(n \log n)$ time in both 2D and 3D. Code to achieve that time complexity in 3D is
quite difficult, so usually the much simpler $O(n^2)$ algorithms are used in 3D.
Code is available from a number of sources, including [my own](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html).

There are various strategies to avoid listing each red point $B$ (which would
require time proportional to $|B|$).
The simplest is to record the start and end cell in each $x$-axis-parallel
lattice-segment
inside the hull, which could be accomplished by intersecting the hull
with each $x$-lattice-line.

You could also find the largest enclosed axis-parallel rectangle in the hull,
and record that subset of $B$ in bulk.
But then you'd need to supplement this rectangle with what lies outside of it
but still in the hull, which may reduce to the lattice-segments approach above.

Comment: Do I need to calculate the convex hull? All I need to do is test if the points are within the convex hull. I'm not sure which way is faster yet though. I do need the set of points in $B$ at the end of the day.

Comment: Thinking about this further, if I were only to test a single point, it is likely faster not to compute the convex hull, but given your suggestion, at first glance it would speeds things up significantly.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable: I don't know how you could determine if a single point is in the hull without knowing the hull itself, at least implicitly. But perhaps I misunderstand your intent...

Comment: See this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11731437/868679 - simply testing whether a hyperplane exists between a given point and the pointcloud will determine whether the point is within the convex hull or not (via linear programming/SVM or any other classification technique). My intentions were to maximize on this fact and potentially have a faster algorithm.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable: I think, in fact, that is a slower algorithm. But about now the software will tell us to cease the private conversation. :-)